# error when generating devise routes in ap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create an api and I am following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/@jiggs/rails-api-doorkeeper-devise), I created my project with `rails new my_api_exper --api`, I added the gems of doorkeeper and devise in the gemfile, I created the subfolder "api" inside controller, and inside "api" I created "v1", I generated the devise controllers, and when adding the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: 'api' do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      devise_for :users, controllers: {
           registrations: 'api/v1/users/registrations',
       }, skip: [:sessions, :password]
    end
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
jef@jef-pc:~/sites/sites/my_api_exp$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        81: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        80: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        79: from /home/luis/sites/sites/my_api_exp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        78: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        77: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        76: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        75: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        74: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        73: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        72: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        71: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        70: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        69: from /home/luis/sites/sites/my_api_exp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        68: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        67: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        66: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        65: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        64: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        63: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        62: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        61: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        60: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        59: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        58: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        57: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        56: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        55: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        54: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
        53: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
        52: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
        51: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
        50: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
        49: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        48: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        47: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        46: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        45: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        44: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        43: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        42: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        41: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
        40: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
        39: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
        38: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
        37: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
        36: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        35: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        34: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        33: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        32: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        31: from /home/luis/sites/sites/my_api_exp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        30: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
        29: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        28: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        27: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        26: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        25: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        24: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        23: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        22: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        21: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        20: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        19: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        18: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        17: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        16: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:184:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        15: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
        14: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
        13: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `block in updater'
        12: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in `reload!'
        11: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        10: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
         9: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
         8: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
         7: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
         6: from /home/luis/sites/sites/my_api_exp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<main>'
         5: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:408:in `draw'
         4: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:426:in `eval_block'
         3: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:426:in `instance_exec'
         2: from /home/luis/sites/sites/my_api_exp/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
         1: from /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:887:in `scope'
/home/luis/sites/sites/my_api_exp/config/routes.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': uninitialized constant ApiConstraints (NameError)
```

what could it be?

Comment: It says right in the error message. ApiConstraints is not initialized

Comment: Read the error. It says: `uninitialized constant ApiConstraints (NameError)`

Comment: What _is_ `ApiConstraints`? Neither you, nor that website you've linked, seem to have defined it. I think you're following an incomplete tutorial, which isn't super helpful. At a guess, I think it's supposed to be something like [this](https://gitlab.coko.foundation/INK/ink-api/blob/6daec95103f1f725057b878b36e60b4bca7b11f4/lib/api_constraints.rb)? So to fix the error, you might need to define that file and then possibly add `require 'api_constraints'` to `config/routes.rb`.